# Cannot create GrpcChannel in Uno Platform WebAssembly (System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, webassembly, uno-platform, grpc-web

I am trying to do a sample of *Uno Platform* using *gRPC-Web*.

Therefore I got inspired by [the content provided by this article](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/15/How-to-use-gRPC-Web-with-Blazor-WebAssembly-on-App-Service.html). I followed the instructions of the article and created a *BlazorApp* which used a weather service with *gRPC-Web*. After that I also included an other service, the counter service, as seen in [this gRPC-Web example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Counter).

After everthing was working, I added a *Uno Platform WebAssembly* app to replace the *BlazorApp* client.

###### Current Problem:

When trying to create a `GrpcChannel` the application gets a `System.NullReferenceException`.

The code snippet for creating the channel looks like this:

```
var baseUri = "https://localhost:44366";
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new GrpcChannelOptions());
```

This is exactly the same code as used in the *BlazorApp*.

The sample code for the *BlazorApp* and the *Uno Platform WebAssembly* can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/t-sorger/UnoGrpcWebAssemblyDemo).

Any idea/suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry @enigmativity, but did you properly read the question before closing it? This is a very legitimate question, for which the answer is completely appropriate. A nullreference in the question title does not necessarily mean that people want to know about null references...

Comment: @JérômeLaban - It seems like solving for the `NullReferenceException` would help here. Can you tell me how you would determine when the duplicate is appropriate or not?

Comment: The already provided answer gives what's needed to understand the issue here. Are you closing it because you did not find all the relevant context in the question itself?

Comment: @JérômeLaban - I'm not asking about this specific question. I'm asking how you would determine when the `NullReferenceException` duplicate is appropriate or not? What rule should I apply in my help to know if it's a duplicate or not? The question, as I read it, is that the OP is getting a `NullReferenceException` and the duplicate is about dealing with such an exception.

Comment: By reading the question, and trying what the OP is asking about. 

If you're not in position to determine whether the `NullReferenceException` is the cause or a side-effect (which was the case here), you should not be closing it as duplicate. A simple comment about "have you tried looking at this nullreference question" would have helped.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I'm the one providing the answer and your generic _NullReferenceException_ post can't help the problem provided by Tom here. The problem was the usage of a sync version of a method where the async version is required because of the environment. The Null stuff there is just the error message you'll get when this happen, it is not related to a NULL REF in the application code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I analyzed your code and I found 4 problems in your code:

1. You were using the Blazor IoC Container. Uno is not designed to use it out-of-the-box. [There some ways to use a container](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/external/uno.extensions/doc/Overview/Hosting/HostingOverview.html), but there's more work to do. To fix this, I simply moved the gRPC service initialization into the `MainPage.xaml.cs` instead. That's not production quality, but it serves the purpose of demoing gRPC.
2. You were calling the *SYNC* version of `.IncrementCount()`. This is not possible on WASM since it's not possible to block the *main thread* in WASM (actually, it's possible, but you need to use primitives hidden deep in JavaScript and it won't solve your problem anyway). That's why on Blazor you need to call `.IncrementCountAsync()`. The same requirements are present on WASM.
3. The XAML of your page were using a `<Grid>` without any *rows*, so each elements were drawn one over the other. I replaced it with a `<StackPanel>` to have a better result.
4. Is was required to activate CORS on the server because the host name + port is slightly different.

I published a working version on a [Fork I did of your project](https://github.com/carldebilly/SO-UnoGrpcWebAssemblyDemo)  **IT WORKS!!**

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and your pull request. Finally, it is working.